# Wayland Touchpad Natural zoom no longer works on Chrome

Tags: chrome, wayland, pop-os

Until Chrome 105.0.5195.52, I could open `chrome://flags/#ozone-platform-hint`, set the toggle to 'Wayland' and upon restarting the browser, touchpad pinch zoom works (natural zoom, not to be confused with dpi zoom which also can be done using ctrl +/-)

It no longer does.

```
OS + version: Pop!_OS 22.04 
CPU architecture (32-bit / 64-bit): 64 bit
Window manager: Mutter on Wayland
```

[I have also reported the same to bugs.chromium.org](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1358658&q=&can=4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is fixed since 106.0.5249.51 (Official Build) beta (64-bit)